# Does cats have an equivalent of traverseM from scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

Is there a function equivalent to `traverseM` from scalaz in cats? I haven't found anything that matches the type signature. Here is the signature and description from the scalaz scala docs:

```
final def traverseM[A, G[_], B](fa: F[A])(f: (A) ⇒ G[F[B]])(implicit G: Applicative[G], F: Bind[F]): G[F[B]]
```

> A version of traverse where a subsequent monadic join is applied to
>   the inner result.

It was fairly simple to define `traverseM` myself based on other functions in cats but I would prefer to use a function from the library if it is available.

Comment: `traverseM` is added in the newest release of cats ([v0.6.0](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v0.6.0))

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [flatTraverse](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala#L50)

The type signature is

```
flatTraverse[G[_], A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[F[B]])(implicit G: Applicative[G], F: FlatMap[F]): G[F[B]]
```

Which is more or less the same as the signature of `traverseM` you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter pointed out, from the version `0.6.0`, there is `traverseM` as part of `Traverse`:

```scala
 /**
   * A traverse followed by flattening the inner result.
   */
  def traverseM[G[_], A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[F[B]])(implicit G: Applicative[G], F: FlatMap[F]): G[F[B]]
```